# SALT_LEN = m2.PKCS5_SALT_LEN AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PKCS5_SALT_LEN'

Tags: python, python-2.7, m2crypto

I installed M2Crypto as per this guide: 
https://github.com/dsoprea/M2CryptoWindows

I run this command:

```
C:\grr-build\M2Crypto-master>C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install
```

Then, I got this which confirms to me that the M2Crypto module has been successfully installed:

```
Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\m2crypto-0.22.3-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
Processing dependencies for M2Crypto==0.22.3
Finished processing dependencies for M2Crypto==0.22.3
```

When I try to test the `import M2Crypto` in a python script, when I run the test script, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator.e-Administrator\Desktop\Pytest\test.py", line
>   2, in 
>       import M2Crypto   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto__init__.py", line 24, in
>   
>       import ASN1   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto\ASN1.py", line 12, in 
>       import BIO   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto\BIO.py", line 221, in 
>       class CipherStream(BIO):   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto\BIO.py", line 227, in
>   CipherStrea m
>       SALT_LEN = m2.PKCS5_SALT_LEN AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PKCS5_SALT_LEN'

Knowing that I skipped one step in the guide given in the link above which was about installing M2Crypto patch because I did not get how to perform it.

Can you please help me? What is the problem with M2Crypto and how to solve it?

Comment: Hey, did you find the root of this problem? I'm facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PKCS5_SALT_LEN'" was a bug in M2Crypto 0.22.3, and has been fixed in in 0.22.4 (https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto/issues/60). Just upgrade M2Crypto and the problem ought to be gone:

```
$ pip uninstall M2Crypto
Uninstalling M2Crypto-0.22.3:
  ...
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled M2Crypto-0.22.3
$ pip install M2crypto  
Collecting M2crypto
Downloading M2Crypto-0.22.5.tar.gz (80kB)
...
Successfully installed M2crypto-0.22.5
```

Before the upgrade, running `import M2Crypto` gave the error as reported in the question; after the upgrade the import succeeded without any problems.